# Determine how many bytes of a request have been read/received?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, file-upload, httpwebrequest

Just wondering if anyone has any idea how you can determine how many bytes of a request have been read/received by the server... In other words how do I stream http request...

In that, users are uploading files and I want to report on a perotic basis how many bytes have been read/received so far.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I might do this...

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `Request.ContentLength`?

Comment: I'm not looking for the total length of the request, but how much of the reqest has been downloaded thus far... i.e. the user is uploading a 20mb file, the web server has thus far downloaded 1.5mb of the 20mb...